# limit of integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We know $1\leq m<n-1$, now I want to see what happens to following limit:
$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{\delta^2}^\delta t^{-m-2}\sin^{n-1}(t)\ dt$$

I guess we don't have explicit result for the integration. So I think $\sin(t)\sim t$ as $t\rightarrow 0^+$, thus we see above is equivalent to
$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{\delta^2}^{\delta}t^{n-m-3}\ dt=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{n-m-2}(\delta^{n-m-2}-\delta^{2(n-m-2)})=0$$
as long as $n-m-2> 0.$ Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you, I also convinced myself by expanding $\sin(t)$, higher order terms would vanish.